# add a user and role programatically

Tags: 7, users

I am using the following code to add a user:

```
  $roles = user_roles();
  $userinfo = array(
  'name' => 'user2',
  'pass' => '123456',
  'init' => 'user2d',
  'status' => 1,
  'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
  // This is where we are different from the default function.
  'roles'        => array(array_search('student', $roles) => 6),

);
$account = user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $userinfo);
```

I am getting this error message:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 column name is not        unique: 
INSERT INTO {users} (uid, name, pass, created, access, status, init) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => user2 [2] => $S$DrkIg0KuBFO12eQ9nQ5ViSx4ydfcWS0nS1TMvaTjYyZyfmVniGgh [3] => 1333135061 [4] => 1333135061 [5] => 1 [6] => user2d ) in drupal_write_record() 
(line 6975 of
```

I am wondering if someone can explain what is going wrong with me trying to add a role. ......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`drupal_anonymous_user()` gives you an object with a `uid` that is considered *empty* by PHP. This means, your call to [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7) will try to insert a new user into the database. The insert operation fails, because a user with the name *user2* already exists in the database.

Comment: thank you that was a very clear and concise answer. I will remember when i see that error again what to look for.